# How can I convert anonymous object HTML attributes to a Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm providing an extra overload to RadioButtonFor and want to add a Key Value pair to the HTML Attributes that are passed in.

As an example I am passing in something like:

```
new { id = "someID" }
```

When i the use the HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes method as seems to be the suggestions I'm finding), its resulting in a dictionary with 4 items with Keys of "Comparer", "Count", "Keys", "Values". I then try to use Reflection to iterate over the values in both "Keys" and "Values", but cannot get that to work either.

Essentially all I want to do is to be able to cast the htmlAttributes to an IDictionary , add a item and then pass it on to a regular RadioButtonFor method.

Edit:
Heres what Im actually trying to do. Provide an overload called isDisabled to be able to set the disabled state of the radio button as this cant be easily done directly using HTML attributes because disabled = false stillr esults in disabled being rendered to tag and disables the radio.

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, bool isDisabled, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var linkAttributes = System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var a in linkAttributes)
        {
            if (a.Key.ToLower() != "disabled")
            {
                htmlAttributesDictionary.Add(a.Key, a.Value);
            }
        }

        if (isDisabled)
        {
            htmlAttributesDictionary.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        return InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, value, htmlAttributesDictionary);
    }
```

Comment: `RadioButtonFor()` already has an overload to add html attributes. What are you actually trying to do. Show the code for your method.

Comment: Updated question with actual code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you might be applying the AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes either twice or to the wrong item.

Without more of your code, it's hard to tell

```
var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new { id = "someID" });
attributes.Count = 1
attributes.Keys.First() = id
```

compared with

```
var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new { id = "someID" }));
attributes.Count = 3
attributes.Keys.Join = Count,Keys,Values
```

When writing your overload, make sure your parameter is: `object htmlAttributes` for the `new { }` part with an overload with the `IDictionary`, eg:

```
Public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButtonFor(..., object htmlAttributes)
{
    return MyRadioButtonFor(...., HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttrbites(htmlAttributes);
}

public static MvcHtmlString MyRadioButtonFor(..., IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    htmlAttributes.Add("item", item);
    return RadioButtonFor(..., htmlAttributes);
}
```

(just to be clear, never use My... - it's just for illustration)

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear why you would not just use and existing overload that accepts `object htmlAttributes` to add the `disabled="disabled"` attribute, however the following should work

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, bool isDisabled, object htmlAttributes)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    if (isDisabled && !attributes.ContainsKey("disabled"))
    {
        attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    return InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, value, attributes);
}
```

Comment: in the view var isDisabled= false; Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsAircraftAndNotAsset, "true",new { id = "rdoIsAircraftAndNotAssetYes", disabled = isDisabled}) Still results in a disabled Radio. I was unable to find any other way to get round this

Comment: Of course it does - `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled="true"` and `disabled="false"` and `disabled="anything"` all set the disabled attribute (even though all but the first is invalid html). That's why I asked _What are you actually trying to do_ in my first comment.

Comment: I'm trying to set the disabled state of a radio button based on a property of the model.

Comment: You could do it with a conditional `? :` in the normal html helper but if you use this regularly then a custom helper is a good idea. The `!attributes.ContainsKey("disabled")` in my answer could probably be removed since you wont be adding that anyway but you may want to add a check for `htmlAttributes == null` in case you are not adding any other attributes and actually pass `null` for the last parameter (in which case build a new `Dictionary<string, object>`)